# Difference in calling groovy methods

Tags: groovy

Method

```
def UserRole (User u, Role r, boolean flush = false) {
 ...
}
```

can be called like this `UserRole.create(u, r, true)`

but erroneously calling it with `UserRole.create(u, r, flush: true)` results in

> No signature of method: UserRole.create() is applicable for argument
>   types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap....

I know its a wrong way to call it but I'm trying to understand why the `LinkedHashMap` error comes and also how the GORM built-in save method works...because calling `User.save(flush: true)` works fine.

Comment: you mean "called like `new UserRole(u,r,true)` - or it's `class UserRole { static void create... }`?  also note, that groovy has no named params (like python).  the `flush: true` is just short for `[flush: true]` and this is passing a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error because `flush : true` is interpreted like a Map with one key-value element.
Groovy does not support named parameters in methods.

> because calling User.save(flush: true) works fine

I did not work with Grails, but `save()` seems to be a default built-in method in GORM framework. If you check the method implementation, you will most likely see that it accepts `Map` in method parameters.